# Rescue cats- letting them outdoors ? Together or alone

Tags: cats, multi-pet-families, adoption

Leo and Tiggy have been living with us for just a month. Leo has trust problems - goodness knows what has gone on in his 3 yr old life before, but he is coming to accept love now. We hoped to let them into the garden together, do you think we should do this in a few weeks one at a time? The

Comment: did you finish this question? You've left it at the start of a new sentence.

Comment: please add some more information about the garden,size and if there is a lot of traffic close by people or cars,cats or dogs that might disturb your cats.the outdoors can be scary for cats at first,if possible leave the door open and stay close to the cats at least so they can see you while they explore the area.

Comment: Hi since i last wrote, things got really tricky and on letting them both out after a month, Tiggy was fine, but Leo suddenly decided that although he came in for food once a day, it was much better outside and he would sleep there too!  I went through agonies seeing his little face peeping out from the flower beds, bushes etc, but last night - whoopee - he came in, ate and went straight to his bed to sleep!  Today he has accepted lots of cuddles and brushing in the house and garden, and I am waiting to see if he will come in again tonight.  I feel very relieved - so far!

Comment: Are they family? Were they rescued together? Our two (rescue) cats are sisters, who survived in the wild together, so they have a team mentality. One of them is really apprehensive of everything, but they do rely on eachother (the confident one can convince the apprehensive one that something is safe).

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me.  Unfortunately, the problem has been solved in an awful way, as Leo - the tricky to handle boy - was fatally knocked over by a courier van recently.  Tiggy the surviving female took a bit to settle down after this, but is now a normal, affectionate and gorgeous 
only cat, and she loves it.